# What Jarkov stands for?

Tags: выбор-имени

Does Jarkov mean Ярков or Жарков?

Comment: And where did you see it?

Comment: @Dmitry Alexandrov In Wikipedia in articles related to WWII, as a placename

Comment: Cannot google it. Are you sure that it was *English* Wikipedia? If Spanish, then that is _Харьков_.

Comment: @Dmitry Alexandrov yes, its english one

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the original article? It may help research.

Comment: Please add some additional context to your question  - in what exactly context you've met this name  and why exactly it's difficult to figure out what's the right answer.

Comment: @shabunc c'mon this is a question from 2015 do you think it warrants being put on hold after all these years during which it wasn't put on hold?

Answer (score 5):

Probably Жарков, being the more common surname; "French" transliteration was used in Soviet and Russian travel passports until about the late 90s. If, however, the presumed language of the transliteration is a Nordic one, or Italian, or any other one where *j* is iotic and *v* is not [f], then Ярков is more likely.

Answer (score 4):

It would seem to be the Spanish name for [Харьков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2): 
*[Járkov](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A1rkov)*

Answer (score 1):

Transliteration into Latin characters - for passports of the Russian Federation (since 16.03.2010)

Жарков -  ZHARKOV

Ярков -   IARKOV

Джарков - DZHARKOV

http://mishka.travel/default/index/passport/

Answer (score 1):

[МАМОНТ ЖАРКОВА](http://library.ua/modules/boonex/blogs/blogs.php?action=show_member_post&post_id=48)

Found it in English wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarkov_Mammoth

Answer (score -1):

1. I think in case of the mammoth he (discoverer) was ***Ярков***.

But the French Wikipedia stands for Zharkov (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarkov_(mammouth) )

2. Excuse me, my first hypotesis is wrong. Here is the link (https://kocmi.ru/mamont-zharkova.html) to the russian source with the correct discoverer's surname (so it is ***Жарков***).